# Date's prototype methods are not enumerable. How to obtain a list of them to iterate?

Tags: javascript, reflection

I want to iterate over the methods of a javascript Date object.  The first attempt did not work:

```
var date = new Date();
for (var key in date) {
    console.log(key);
}
```

I've tried a few related things -- `Object.keys`, for example.  So far I have not found a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames):

> The Object.getOwnPropertyNames() method returns an array of all
>   properties (including non-enumerable properties except properties that
>   using Symbol) found directly upon a given object.

So [Object.getOwnPropertyNames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) will produce the list I was looking for when called directly on the prototype object:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Date.prototype)
```

Comment: The important difference is that you're operating on `Date.prototype` rather than a `Date` object.

Comment: No, the important difference is that the methods are not enumerable, and that Object.getOwnPropertyNames includes non-enumerable properties, while `for ... in` does not.  `for (var key in Date.prototype) console.log(key)` comes up empty as well.